# How do I correctly place shape size in this data by showing all three variables in geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data and code below. I want to accurately reflect the Nucleotides for their corresponding size in `Size` column. If you check the statistics for the data, you can clearly see T is largest in totalSize then A is second largest which is not showing correctly in my plot. What is wrong with my plot code below?

```
#check some statistics:
counts <- aggregate(Size~Nucleotides,all.data,length)
names(counts)[2] <- 'counts'
totalSize <- aggregate(Size~Nucleotides,all.data,sum)
names(totalSize)[2] <- 'totalSize'
merge(counts,totalSize)

# Nucleotides counts totalSize
# 1           A      6 24.700016
# 2           C      6  3.001356
# 3           G      6  5.155665
# 4           T      6 37.471940
```

Plot code:

```
p <- ggplot(all.data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Pos, y = Size, color = bases,group = Samples, shape = Samples, size = Nucleotides))+
  # geom_point(aes(x=Pos, y = Size, color = bases,group = Samples, shape = Samples))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=1:nlevels(all.data$Samples)) +
  theme_bw() 
p
```

Data:

```
all.data <- structure(list(Pos = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Nucleotides = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    Size = c(0.80519048411246, 0.375977374812843, 10.6754283813009, 
    0.495757777408085, 0.615538180003327, 0.329396107136916, 
    0.835135584761271, 0.562302445516553, 1.11795042422226, 0.246215272001331, 
    0.339377807353186, 20.0931625353519, 1.06859576968273, 0.264394829612221, 
    11.510428907168, 0.554494712103408, 0.624265569917744, 0.381903642773208, 
    0.829905992949471, 0.631609870740306, 1.17876028202115, 0.334165687426557, 
    0.290099882491187, 16.1689189189189), Samples = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Ago2_SsHV2L_1_CATGGC_L003_R1_001", 
    "Ago2_SsHV2L_2_CATTTT_L003_R1_001"), class = "factor"), bases = c("21", 
    "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", 
    "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", 
    "21", "21", "21")), .Names = c("Pos", "Nucleotides", "Size", 
"Samples", "bases"), row.names = c("1.A", "2.A", "3.A", "1.C", 
"2.C", "3.C", "1.G", "2.G", "3.G", "1.T", "2.T", "3.T", "1.A1", 
"2.A1", "3.A1", "1.C1", "2.C1", "3.C1", "1.G1", "2.G1", "3.G1", 
"1.T1", "2.T1", "3.T1"), reshapeLong = structure(list(varying = list(
    c("A", "C", "G", "T")), v.names = "Mismatches", idvar = "Pos", 
    timevar = "Nucleotides"), .Names = c("varying", "v.names", 
"idvar", "timevar")), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why do you map "Nucleotides" to the `size` aesthetic and not "Size"?

Comment: It's unclear what you're hoping to see. Could you describe your desired output or, better yet, draw a mockup?

Comment: I want to show the totalSize value reflect in the plot. So as shown by the stats above, I want `T` and `A` to have larger shapes in the plot.

Comment: Is there a way we can use `merge(counts,totalSize)` information and paste the `totalSize` for `Nucleotides` in the plot in graphical format?

Comment: In the plot, all I want to show is the size of Nucleotides as per totalSize values for those nucleotides as we have from `merge(counts,totalSize)`.

Comment: @Elin That's right, it doesn't include the total size. So how can we show that in the plot based on `merge(counts,totalSize)`?

Comment: You need to store those results in a data frame and use that data frame to make your graph.  So you want totalSize as the y variable, what is the x variable? Nucleotides?

Comment: @Elin No, Size and Pos are correctly placed in Y and X axes. I just want to paste the circle size in the same plot to show the Nucleotides totalSize distribution for `all.data`.

Comment: @Elin The size of Nucleotide is irrespective of the shape of Samples.

Comment: The counts are all 6, what is it you are trying to do with them?

Comment: @Elin There are two samples, so each sample has 3 replicates of Nucleoties. Hence they are 6 all across. I am only interested in the Nucloetide's totalSize from `merge(counts,totalSize)`.

Comment: So why are you merging and not just using totalSize since counts just adds a column of 6s?

Comment: Are you saying you just want to put the mean size for each Nucleotide?

Comment: @Elin totalSize is the aggregated size of Nucleotides and that's what I want to show.

Comment: Well ghat wil make you y axis much longer, right? Because it's summing up the values of the sizes and the other points are all based on one observation.  It does not really make sense to me to have a giant gap like that in the graph but maybe someone else in you field will get what you mean better.

Comment: Run the plot I posted, you would have to extend your y axis up to 40 to include all of your points.

Comment: @Elin No, it will not distort the current plot in any way. I just want to have this information as legend only.

Comment: If you just want to put something in a legend you should add it as text or a second graph.   The totalSize is not an attribute of the individual data points.

Comment: @Elin That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows how to summarize values and join them back to the original data frame so that they can be directly referenced in the ggplot.This uses the same aggregation code provide (not verified)

```
#check some statistics:
counts <- aggregate(Size~Nucleotides,all.data,length)
names(counts)[2] <- 'counts'
totalSize <- aggregate(Size~Nucleotides,all.data,sum)
names(totalSize)[2] <- 'totalSize'

## compute the summary and join with detail dataframe
summarized <- merge(counts,totalSize, sort = T)
merged <- merge(all.data, summarized, by ="Nucleotides")

## make a summarized label column example  "A 24.70"
summarized$NucleotidesTotalSize <- paste(summarized$Nucleotides, format(round(summarized$totalSize,2), nsmall=2))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(merged) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Pos, y = Size, shape = Samples, size = totalSize, color = bases))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=1:nlevels(all.data$Samples)) +
  # use the summarized dataframe for labelling and breaks
  scale_size(name = "Nucleotides Total Size", breaks = summarized$totalSize, labels=summarized$NucleotidesTotalSize) +
  theme_bw() 

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't tell you anything about the total size of Nucleotides (A,T,G,C)

Comment: @MAPK,please clarify what you expect - an earlier comment is "I want T and A to have larger shapes in the plot."  - This can be seen in this chart.  Do you need something in the legend, or color by Nucleotides?

Comment: No, I just want Nuclotides totalSize shown on the legend. No need to make any change on the plot I have at the moment. Just want Nucleotide totalSize on the legend.

Comment: Edited to add total size labelling.